# Content going through fixed header when scrolling

Tags: css

I am currently trying to make a clone of the facebook website however I am encountering issues with the fixed position header. After scrolling down the mainBar goes through the header bar and I cannot find a way to fix it, not even using Z-index fixes this issue.

Please look at the .header and mainBar and tell me how to fix this so that the content no longer goes through the headerbar, and the headerbar stays in a fixed postion and scrolls with the page like normal.

Thank you

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f2f5;
}

/* this part is for the header */

.header {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.leftHeader {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: left;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
}

.searchBar {
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.searchBtn {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.searchLogo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.inputText {
  background-color: lightgray;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  width: 175px;
  height: 15px;
}

.centerHeader {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 50px;
}

.centerHeader i {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.rightHeader {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: right;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 20px;
}

.rightHeader i {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.profilePic img {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/* This part is for the main */

.mainBar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.stories_Reels_Box {
  height: 300px;
  width: 75%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

.box_Two {
  height: 300px;
  width: 75%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a35cda4da8.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="leftHeader">
        <img class="logo" src="images/Facebook-logo.png" />
        <div class="searchBar">
          <img class="searchBtn" src="images/search-icon.webp" />
          <input type="text" class="inputText" placeholder="Search Facebook" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="centerHeader">
        <div class="home">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-house" style="color: #000000"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="watch">
          <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-tv" style="color: #000000"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="marketplace">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-shop" style="color: #000000"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-user-group" style="color: #000000"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rightHeader">
        <div class="menu">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" style="color: #000000"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="message">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-messenger" style="color: #000000"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="notification">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-bell" style="color: #000000"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="profilePic">
          <img
            src="/images/ProgrammingIllustration.png"
            alt="profile_picture"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mainBar">
      <div class="stories_Reels_Box"></div>
      <div class="box_Two"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="leftSidebar"></div>

    <div class="rightBar"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

header has no background color. Add a background color to it so anything behind it is not visible.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #f1f2f5;
}

/* this part is for the header */

.header {
  background-color: #eee; /*  this */
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.leftHeader {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: left;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.logo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 75px;
}

.searchBar {
  background-color: lightgray;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.searchBtn {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.searchLogo {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}

.inputText {
  background-color: lightgray;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  width: 175px;
  height: 15px;
}

.centerHeader {
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 50px;
}

.centerHeader i {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.rightHeader {
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  align-items: right;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 20px;
}

.rightHeader i {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.profilePic img {
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/* This part is for the main */

.mainBar {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  background-color: red;
}

.stories_Reels_Box {
  height: 300px;
  width: 75%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: white;
}

.box_Two {
  height: 300px;
  width: 75%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a35cda4da8.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <div class="leftHeader">
        <img class="logo" src="images/Facebook-logo.png" />
        <div class="searchBar">
          <img class="searchBtn" src="images/search-icon.webp" />
          <input type="text" class="inputText" placeholder="Search Facebook" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="centerHeader">
        <div class="home">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-house" style="color: #000000"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="watch">
          <i class="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-tv" style="color: #000000"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="marketplace">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-shop" style="color: #000000"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="group">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-user-group" style="color: #000000"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="rightHeader">
        <div class="menu">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-bars" style="color: #000000"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="message">
          <i class="fa-brands fa-facebook-messenger" style="color: #000000"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="notification">
          <i class="fa-solid fa-bell" style="color: #000000"></i>
        </div>

        <div class="profilePic">
          <img
            src="/images/ProgrammingIllustration.png"
            alt="profile_picture"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="mainBar">
      <div class="stories_Reels_Box"></div>
      <div class="box_Two"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="leftSidebar"></div>

    <div class="rightBar"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```